# Can you modify the number of slidesPerView in swiperjs after it was init?

Tags: javascript, swiper.js

I am trying to modify the number of the slides per view in swiperjs after it was initiated.
In the API I couldn't find any method that allow me to update that.
Currently the swiper is created with 1 slide per view and I would like to change it to 3 per view after it was initiated.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved it by modify the params.

```
let params = swiperModify.params;
params.slidesPerView = 3;
params.slidesPerColumn = 3;
```

For some reason at first I was looking for a method to handle new params (set method).. but this works perfectly fine. If that not best practice I would like to know :)

Comment: This partially worked for me But I also had to call the update function : 

const params = swiperModify.params;
params.slidesPerView = 3;
swiperModify.update()